# Can I bind to an element that was loaded with jquery.load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am pretty new to JQuery so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

I am loading html into a div with this line of code:

```
$('#add_notes').load('index.php?route=module/notes/insert&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&customer_id=<?php echo $customer_id; ?>');
```

The loaded file contains a button/link listed below:

```
<a id="button_notes" class="button"><?php echo $button_add_note; ?></a>
```

Everything displays the way it should however I am trying to attach a click listener to the button/link in the main file using this syntax:

```
$('#button_notes').bind('click', function() {
    alert("ok");

});
```

From what I can tell there is nothing wrong with my code; so my question is, since the button/link node was loaded dynamically am I not able to bind to it? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Check documentation about `on` and "event delegation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use delegation. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#button_notes', function() {
    alert("ok");
});
```

**From the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):**

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. [...] Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; **they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call** to .on().

Which means you need to attach the event handler to a existing element and then use delegation  by using `.on()`

Comment: Ok one more question along the same lines. Not an event handler, but I still want to get the value of fields in the file I am loading. because I want to send values to a php script via ajax so I have $('#tab-notes input[name=\'note_for\']').val() to try an grab the value of <input name="note_for"> but it keeps getting returned undefined.Im sure it easy; my searches however have been in vain.

Comment: @user3167249 when do you run that code? Can you post thst html?

Comment: I am putting it in the data variable for the ajax array. This is the actual code... data: 'for_array=' + encodeURIComponent($('#tab-notes input[name=\'note_for\']').val()) +
   '&type=' + encodeURIComponent($('#tab-notes select[name=\'type\']').val()) +
   '&note=' + encodeURIComponent($('#tab-notes textarea[name=\'note\']').val()) +
   '&ccs=' + encodeURIComponent($('#tab-notes radio[name=\'ccs\']').attr('checked')) +

Comment: @user3167249, is that input descendent of #tab-notes? Try this: `console.log($('#tab-notes input[name="note_for"]'));` what do you get?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45031/discussion-between-user3167249-and-sergio)